# How would I go abouce decodeURI with c#/asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, uri

I have a webservice which is passed some encoded material.

Javascript:

```
var x = encodeURIComponent(data);
```

But when `X` is sent to the server, I am unable to decode it. I was looking through the namespaces HTTP, and URI, but was having trouble finding the exact thing I wanted as I tried `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`  and `Uri.EscapeUriString()` to no avail.

How is this done?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` instead of `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`.

Comment: sweet.   Thanks, it seems like that is the answer that is working.  I was looking at at very lengthy article about it:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yangxind/archive/2006/11/09/don-t-use-net-system-uri-unescapedatastring-in-url-decoding.aspx